# "User removed" reputation change

Tags: support

I saw in my reputation report a line saying -8 points and the comment is "User was removed" without any link. What does that mean?
[image: reputation]
I assume that some user was deleted. But in this case shouldn't the value be -5 or -10 or -15 or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point. I would never notice this fact.

My option the user could down-vote some of your answers which will decrease you score and then when the user was removed increased it again.